# CKEditor 4 - Removing Image Toolbar Button Causes Image Dialog to No Longer Display Width and Height Properties

Tags: ckeditor, ckeditor4.x

I am using CKEditor 4 and trying to customize a toolbar to show to non-Admin users of our software. I know how to remove the "Image" button from the toolbar to prevent non-Admins from inserting image elements into our templates. However, I still want them to be able to edit an existing image within a template by double-clicking on it. With the Image insert button removed, I can still perform this action and the resulting dialog displays the source, alt text, and image preview portions. But, the Width, Height, and Ratio Lock controls are hidden. Upon inspecting the markup, it looks as though the table of class `cke_dialog_ui_hbox` that resides several nodes up from the `txtWidth` container has an inline display style set to `none`.

**Is there a way to hide / not show the Insert Image toolbar button while still displaying the width, height, and ratio lock controls in the Image dialog box?**

I have tried using `config.removeButtons` as well as `config.toolbar` and specifying the buttons that I want displayed in the `insert` group but the presence of the button or not appears to impact the plugin functionality by arbitrarily hiding certain controls.

Comment: I am at the point where I am about to use the `CKEDITOR.on('dialogDefinition'...` event handler to get the `txtWidth` content element and find the grandparent node with `display: none` and manually set it to `display: block`.

That's hacky and I don't want to do that. But I don't see any documented official route or reason for why this is happening.

Comment: Addressing the ancestor and setting the style to `display: block` successfully displays the width, height, and rotation lock dialog elements, however, attempting to update the width or height and pressing the "Ok" button does not successfully implement the change which means the plugin must have some validation that is preventing the change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I learned through Fiddling that the `styles` attribute on an `img` definition in the `allowedContent` object determines whether or not the `width` and `height` fields display in the image dialog box.

```
CKEDITOR.editorConfig = function( config ) {
    allowedContent = {
        img: {
            attributes: true,
            classes: true,
            styles: 'width,height'
        }
    }
};
```

Either I  missed that in the documentation somewhere or it just wasn't readily apparent to me.

Fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/a913q0mz/

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like the best solution will be to hide the button with CSS.

In your theme (e.g. `ckeditor/skins/moona-lisa`) open `editor.css` and add this at the bottom:

`a.cke_button.cke_button__image { display: none; }`

Save and do a force refresh (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-[click refresh]) and you should be good.

Comment: Thanks Nathan! It seems obvious in retrospect and I don't know why I didn't try that. I may have to go back and do that if my bug request with the CKEditor maintainers doesn't pan out. I appreciate it and will accept that as a solution.